# A good way to denote a matrix is a column normalized matrix of another matrix

Tags: notation, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

What is a good way to show via mathematical notation that matrix $B$ is equal to column normalized matrix $A$, where we define a normalized column as:

$Ŷ_i = ( y_i – y_\min) ÷ ( y_\max – y_\min)$

Matrix $A$ has $n$ rows and $4$ columns
Matrix $B$ also has $n$ rows and $4$ columns but each column in matrix $A$ has been normalized according to the above formula

MS Word has all the required symbols to express this notation

Comment: What are ymin and ymax here: are they the min and max for the entire matrix, or just for that column?

Comment: they are the max and min just for that column

Comment: In that case you're probably best off just finding a good way to notate how each column vector is defined. At that point you can just say that $B$ is the matrix with column vectors $Y_i$.

Comment: Do you think my notation above is clear enough